# Open source object recognition library for visual browsing interfaces

Tags: web-scraping, image-recognition, browser-automation, object-recognition

Are there any image analysis or object recognition libraries that would be suitable for use in browser emulation? Eg: automation of user logins, filling forms, extracting data from tables, etc.

I understand that HTML parsers are more commonly used than image analysis algorithms for the purpose of browser emulation. However, I would like to automate tasks on websites that frequently change their html code and appearance. I would like to build an "intelligent" scraper that can recongize these visual browser elements in conjunction with conventional browser emulation techniques.

Are there any existing libraries for this purpose? Ones that would be suitable for screenshots of GUIs? (non-photographic images) such as buttons, tables, checkboxes and text?

Answer (score 1):

"[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) automates browsers. That's it."

Comment: Thanks Željko. I wonder if browser automation has ever been used with "intelligent" agents using image analysis for various testing procedures. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by image analysis, does Sikuli do what you need? http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: Yes that is very close, I also found this [list of similiar software](http://www.testandtry.com/2010/02/01/5-great-automation-tools-based-on-image-recognition/) and a [software quality assurance and testing stackexchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/) discussing these options.